# Is Milner let polymorphism a rank 2 feature?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-systems

`let a = b in c` can be thought as a syntactic sugar for `(\a -> c) b`, but in a typed setting in general it's not the case. For example, in the Milner calculus `let a = \x -> x in (a True, a 1)` is typable, but seemingly equivalent `(\a -> (a True, a 1)) (\x -> x)` is not.

However, the latter is typable in System F with a rank 2 type for the first lambda.

My questions are:

- Is let polymorphism a rank 2 feature that sneaked secretly in the otherwise rank 1 world of Milner calculus?
- The purpose of having of separate `let` construct seems to specify which types should be generalized by type checker, and which are not. Does it serve any other purposes? Are there any reasons to extend more powerful systems e.g. System F with separate `let` which is not sugar? Are there any papers on the rationale behind the design of the Milner calculus which no longer seems obvious to me?
- Is there the most general type for `\a -> (a True, a 1)` in System F?
- Are there type systems closed under beta expansion? I.e. if P is typable and M N = P then M is typable?

Some clarifications:

- By equivalence I mean equivalence modulo type annotations. Is 'System F a la Church' the correct term for that?
- I know that in general the principal typing property doesn't hold in F, but a principal type could exist for my particular term.
- By `let` I mean the non-recursive flavour of `let`. Extension of system F with recursive let is obviously useful as it allows for non-termination.

Comment: see this paper as well: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.150.5056

Comment: I'm aware of it. My question is not about let per se, but the let generalization step, which seems to make let equivalent to an application of a rank2 lambda. I will re-read the paper in search for clues to my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

W.r.t. to the four questions asked:

- A key insight in this matter is that rather than just typing a
  lambda-abstraction with a potentially polymorphic argument type, we
  are typing a (sugared) abstraction that is (1) applied exactly once
  and, moreover, that is (2) applied to a statically known argument.
  That is, we can first subject the "argument" (i.e. the definiens of
  the local definition) to type reconstruction to find its
  (polymorphic) type; then assign the found type to the "parameter"
  (the definiendum); and then, finally, type the body in the extended
  type context.

  Note that that is considerably more easy than general rank-2 type
  inference.
- Note that, strictly speaking, let .. = .. in .. is only syntactic sugar in System F if you demand that the definiendum carries a type annotation: let .. : .. = .. in .. .
- Here are two solutions for T in (\a :: T -> (a True, a 1)) in System F: forall b. (forall a. a -> b) -> (b, b) and forall c d. (forall a b. a -> b) -> (c, d). Note that neither one of them is more general than the other. In general, System F does not admit principal types.
- I suppose this holds for the simply typed lambda-calculus?

Comment: Good comments.  IIRC (I am not terribly sure of this), system F requires explicit type lambdas and applications, in which case the two types you gave for question 3 would actually require different terms.  Indeed, that would imply that the original term in question by the OP is not typeable, because `a` would have to be monomorphic.  Am I thinking of a different system, or are we assuming a type-lambda free variant?

Comment: No, you're absolutely right. I was interpreting the problem of finding a most general type as, well, finding a type _and_ completing the untyped term with parameter types, type abstractions, and type applications.

Comment: To proof that there's no principal type you need to show that there's no common supertype for these two typings, and in presense of higher-rank type it's a tough part for me.

Comment: Also, +1 for 'statically known argument'

Comment: @nponeccop: a precision nitpick. you don't have a notion of supertypes because there's no subtype relation. what you want is a most general unifier.

Comment: Oh, I just didn't know that structural unification is still applicable in presence of explicit quantifiers. Is there an entry-level explanation for this anywhere?

Comment: Hmm... I remember some discussion in the various papers on the evolution of GHC's type system. But the general point, if I get your question, is that although there's not always a most general unifier with higher ranked types, there still sometimes is. And when there is, then often (always?) you can find it.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. The "always" part holds in constructivist logics.

Comment: when you have subtyping, by the way, you have a most general unifier by definition.

Comment: I realize this question is a bit old, but I don't think the `P typeable and M N = P => M N typeable` property holds for STLC. `P = 0`, `M = (\x -> if x then 0 else "string")`, `N = true` for example; and I think an example like this works for most languages. Well-typed terms can't go wrong -- but there's nothing to say ill-typed terms can't go right.

Answer (score 4):

Types are not preserved under beta-expansion in any calculus that can express the concept of "dead code". You can probably figure out how to write something similar to this in any usable language:

```
if True then something typable else utter nonsense
```

For example, let `M = (\x y -> x) (something typable)` and `N = (utter nonsense)` and `P = (something typable)`, so that `M N = P`, and `P` is typable, but `M N` isn't.

...rereading your question, I see that you only demand that `M` be typable, but that seems like a very strange meaning to give to "preserved under beta-expansion" to me. Anyway, I don't see why some argument like the above couldn't apply: simply let `M` have some untypable dead code in it.

Comment: Well, the term "preserved under beta expansion" must be completely incorrect then. I just wanted to find a type system without the kind of flaw with `(f True, f 2)` expressed by the Milner calculus where seemingly innocent elimination of lets may lead to untypability. System F seems to be one of such systems according to @StefanHoldermans

Answer (score 3):

You could type `(\a -> (a True, a 1)) (\x -> x)` if instead of generalizing only let expressions, you generalized *all* lambda abstractions. Having done so, one also needs to instantiate type schemas at *every* use point, not simply at the point where the binder which refers to them is actually used. I'm  don't think there's any problem with this actually, outside of the fact that its vastly less efficient. I recall some discussion of this in TAPL, in fact, making similar points.

Comment: but then it's type inference for the rank-2 fragment of system F. The second rank is the highest rank for which type checking is decidable, so I doubt that type inference is decidable too.

Comment: @nponeccop: no it's not. it's a pessimization of hm typechecking. note that you're also instantiating type schemas at every use point. `(\x -> x)` doesn't get a type, it gets a schema. that schema in turn is instantiated twice. neither the `\a` expression nor the `\x` expression gets a type on their own, so to speak.

Comment: Type checking is decidable (given explicit type annotations on parameters, type abstractions, and type applications of course); type inference is decidable for ranks <= 2.

Comment: @sclv isn't a schema the same as having a forall?

Answer (score 2):

I recall many years ago seeing in a book about lambda calculus (possibly Barendregt) a type system preserved by beta expansion.  It had no quantification, but it had disjunction to express that a term needed to be of more than one type simultaneously, as well as a special type omega which every term inhabited.  As I recall, the latter avoids Daniel Wagner's dead code objection.  While every expression was well-typed, restricting the position of omega in the type allowed you to charactize which expressions had (weak?) head normal forms.

Also if I recall correctly, fully normal form expressions had principal types, which did not contain omega.

For example the principal type of \f x -> f (f x) (the Church numeral 2) would be something like ((A -> B) /\ (B -> C)) -> A -> C

Answer (score 0):

Not able to answer all your very specialized questions, but no, its not a rank 2 feature. As you write, it's just that let definitions are being quantified which yields a fully polymorphic rank-1 type unless the definition depends on some monomorphic value ina nouter scope.

Please also note that Haskell `let` is known as `let rec` in other languages and allows definition of mutually recursive functions and values. This is something you would not want to code manually with lambda-expressions and Y-combinators.

Comment: Eh it's not much worse than single parameter. `(\(a,b,c) -> body) (fix (\(a,b,c) -> (defn of a, defn of b, defn of c))`  I guess you have to duplicate the names.

Comment: let rec is impossible to encode in system F, just as the Y, because in  system F there are no diverging terms. Sorry for using haskell syntax for illustrations.

Comment: Also note that if we just have the rank 1 restriction but no `let`, it's not possible to create polymorphic local bindings.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why we have let(rec) in HM typed languages.