# Is a record with polymorphic methods rank 1?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml

From my understanding:

- OCaml uses rank 1 polymorphism
- In rank 1 polymorphism all quantifiers must be at the outermost (prenex) position

However the following is possible to type:

```ml
type 'a myArray = { map : 'b. ('a -> 'b) -> 'b myArray; }
```

Where the type quantifier `'b` is nested. In fact, this [can be used to simulate higher rank polymorphism in OCaml](http://devmusings.legiasoft.com/blog/2008/05/23/higher-rank_polymorphism_in_ocaml)).

So can there be nested type quantifiers in rank-1 polymorphism, such as this case? And the type system is still predicative, i.e. full type inference is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Type inference is still possible because `myArray` is named, giving hints to the type inference.

The moment the typechecker sees a `map` field, it knows to use a `'a myArray` and hence knows exactly where the quantifier should be.

In a way, because a record is named and with a type definition, there is no need to infer what has to be in the type definition. Note that this wouldn't be possible with tuples as they don't rely on an external definition and are fully inferred.

Comment: Right, I get type inference is possible, but would it still work in a rank 1 type system? I could rephrase the question similar to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296695/is-milner-let-polymorphism-a-rank-2-feature - is this a rank 2 feature?

Comment: Not sure, I never really caught what these ranking really refer to. I can tell that what applies in this question you type applies here too. The record, just as the let, allows to generalize (and place the quantifier) where you want to.